# Is It Possible For a Custom Font TextView To Be Configured for this App?

Tags: java, android, xml, fonts

Using Android Studio 1.3 - and based on an online tutorial - I run this app successfully on my android phone, as it is, but I have unsuccessfully tried more than half a dozen different ListView and TextView configurations, some from this excellent stackoverflow site, in order to try to get a custom font to display the text within the .xml. Although I'm using a rooted Android 4.3 to debug and run, I would need to eventually modify and distribute this particular app with a custom font because oem fonts on rooted and unrooted phones and devices lack the repertoire of the local language's characters. I've made the fonts already from Google open source fonts.
Using only the MainActivity.java and the row_site.xml below, is it possible for me to modify the textView to use the custom font that it appears I would place within and distribute from the /assets/fonts folder or would it be helpful if I include other files from this project?

**MainActivity**

```
package com.example.stacksites;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private SitesAdapter mAdapter;
    private ListView sitesList;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.i("StackSites", "OnCreate()");
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Get reference to our ListView
        sitesList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.sitesList);

        //Set the click listener to launch the browser when a row is clicked.
        sitesList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int pos,long id) {
                String url = mAdapter.getItem(pos).getLink();
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                startActivity(i);

            }

        });

        /*
         * If network is available download the xml from the Internet.
         * If not then try to use the local file from last time.
         */
        if(isNetworkAvailable()){
            Log.i("StackSites", "starting download Task");
            SitesDownloadTask download = new SitesDownloadTask();
            download.execute();
        }else{
            mAdapter = new SitesAdapter(getApplicationContext(), -1, SitesXmlPullParser.getStackSitesFromFile(MainActivity.this));
            sitesList.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        }

    }

    //Helper method to determine if Internet connection is available.
    private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager 
              = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
    } 

    /*
     * AsyncTask that will download the xml file for us and store it locally.
     * After the download is done we'll parse the local file.
     */
    private class SitesDownloadTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            //Download the file
            try {
                Downloader.DownloadFromUrl("http://example.com/stacksites.xml", openFileOutput("StackSites.xml", Context.MODE_PRIVATE));
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result){
            //setup our Adapter and set it to the ListView.
            mAdapter = new SitesAdapter(MainActivity.this, -1, SitesXmlPullParser.getStackSitesFromFile(MainActivity.this));
            sitesList.setAdapter(mAdapter);
            Log.i("StackSites", "adapter size = "+ mAdapter.getCount());
        }
    }

}
```

**row_site.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp" >

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iconImg"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nameTxt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/iconImg"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/aboutTxt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/iconImg"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:layout_below="@id/nameTxt"
        />
```

Comment: Check this https://plus.google.com/+LisaWrayZeitouni/posts/LTr5tX5M9mb if the help

Comment: Thank you! I've looked at the site you've generously pointed to.  In which file, and where in it, do I place the:
    "@BindingAdapter({"bind:font"})
    public static void setFont(TextView textView, String fontName){
     textView.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(textView.getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/" + fontName));
    }"

Answer (score 0):

You can put your custom font into assets then try using [Typeface.createFromAsset()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Typeface.html#createFromAsset%28android.content.res.AssetManager,%20java.lang.String%29)

Then `TextView.setTypeface()` passing the created typeface